# .htaccess not letting robot.txt through

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I have the following .htaccess file in my root:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

This works as it should for shortening all my URLs to website.com/something

The problem is Google can't find my `robots.txt` file in my root.  The above file isn't letting it through.  when It type website.com/robots.txt I get a 404 not found.  But if I comment out the above `.htaccess` code I can get to it just fine.

How can I edit my `.htaccess` file to let `robots.txt` through without interfering with my other URLs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
```

Second line will exclude robots.txt from URL rewritting rules .
Try above code

Answer (score 2):

I tried both suggestions and they both work great.  However I went with Kiran's answer simply because it's a shorter syntax.  This is what I ended up with.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

# Allow Robots.txt to pass through
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: In my solution, I explained, how you can exclude not just one file but a list of file & folders altogether!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This rewrites all your requests to index.php?page=, except the files specified in the `RewriteCond` list.

Answer (score 0):

Find the line that already exists in your .htaccess that says this:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
```

And change it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^itemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
```